# birt Problem with json_unquote with mysql

Tags: java, mysql, birt

When i am trying to display the results with json_unquote its showing HEX numbers in the birt.
[image: This is the output when i tried it from workbench]

[image: This is the output when i tried it from Eclipse birt reporting]

DB Script for creation of table:

CREATE TABLE `action_data1` (
`id_ref` bigint NOT NULL,
`data_map` text,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_ref`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Rptdesign was attached [here](https://dpaste.com/33P9LSQYD)

Comment: This is not related to `birt`.  Please show (in text, no pictures) the definition of your table, and some sample data see [mre].

Comment: I added the DB script and RptDesign also attached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql> select json_unquote(json_extract('{"test":"abc"}','$.test')) as test;
+------+
| test |
+------+
| abc  |
+------+
```

It seems to work OK, so more input is needed.

EDIT:

seeing [Brit return Mysql string concatenated field as a blob](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/119804/)

you can try this:

```
select convert(json_unquote(json_extract(data_map,'$')),CHAR);
```

Comment: Yes in Mysql its displaying properly but whereas in birt its showing HEX codes